# Ionic generate page without the module file

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I'm trying to generate a ionic page using ionic CLI with following command,

`ionic g page SomePage --no-module` 

as it said on the documentation. 
But it still generates the module file. When i use the command 

`ionic g page SomePage`

But it generates same files as earlier command. Is there any way I can generate a ionic page using ionic CLI without the **module.ts** file.

Comment: try with `--without-module`

Comment: `Unknown option: '--without-module'
[ERROR] Could not generate page.`